# Firebase Deploy "An unexpected error has occurred"

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

Trying to deploy a new site to Firebase (as I've done a dozen times, though haven't for a few months).  Everything is going fine, but then when I get to "Firebase Deploy", I get "Error: An unexpected error has occurred".  I've tried the suggestions given where a similar question was asked earlier (["An unexpected error has occurred" after firebase deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475477/an-unexpected-error-has-occurred-after-firebase-deploy)) but none of them have done any good (keep getting the same error).  Firebase is updated.  Running on a Linux 64-bit (if it matters).  I ran a debug on the deploy, and got the following log:

```
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.441Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.443Z] Command:       /home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node /home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/firebase deploy
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.443Z] CLI Version:   3.18.5
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.443Z] Platform:      linux
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.443Z] Node Version:  v10.3.0
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.443Z] Time:          Tue Dec 11 2018 14:45:26 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.443Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.448Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.448Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.449Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","open
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.450Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token  
 { refresh_token: '1/9RM51tbmmz5VrjkpAxad-5CElD29bDNC-Dyu-L6-9hw',
  client_id:
   '563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: 'j9iVZfS8kkCEFUPaAeJV0sAi',
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  scope:
   'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase openid' } 
 Tue Dec 11 2018 14:45:26 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:26.674Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:27.581Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/my-home-page-ed336  

 Tue Dec 11 2018 14:45:27 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:27.871Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:27.873Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/my-home-page-ed336/tokens  

 Tue Dec 11 2018 14:45:27 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:28.270Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'my-home-page-ed336'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying hosting
[info] i  hosting: preparing . directory for upload...
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:28.733Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/hosting/my-home-page-ed336/uploads/-LTUDqAhHObNxZ0HsRuG?fileCount=114&message=  

 Tue Dec 11 2018 14:45:28 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:36.863Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 410
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:36.864Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY undefined
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:36.867Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:10:13)
    at Request._callback (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/api.js:47:25)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1157:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1079:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.697Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.699Z] Command:       /home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node /home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/firebase deploy --debug
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.700Z] CLI Version:   3.18.5
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.700Z] Platform:      linux
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.700Z] Node Version:  v10.3.0
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.700Z] Time:          Tue Dec 11 2018 14:45:49 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.700Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.705Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.705Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:49.707Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/my-home-page-ed336  

 Tue Dec 11 2018 14:45:49 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:50.018Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:50.021Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/my-home-page-ed336/tokens  

 Tue Dec 11 2018 14:45:50 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:50.315Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'my-home-page-ed336'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying hosting
[info] i  hosting: preparing . directory for upload...
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:50.768Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/hosting/my-home-page-ed336/uploads/-LTUDvYyTmVMnTOVgYO3?fileCount=114&message=  

 Tue Dec 11 2018 14:45:50 GMT-0700 (MST)
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:57.867Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 410
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:57.868Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY undefined
[debug] [2018-12-11T21:45:57.871Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:10:13)
    at Request._callback (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/api.js:47:25)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1157:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1079:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 3):

Your Firebase CLI is very old.  Update it with `npm install -g firebase-tools`.  Latest version at this moment is 6.1.2.

Comment: Tried updating it with both npm install -g firebase-tools and npm i -g firebase-tools@latest, but when I run firebase --version afterwards, it continues to stay at version 3.18.5.  I also checked to make sure I only have Firebase in one directory with which firebase, and I do.


Any suggestions?  I know this outside the scope of the original issue, but I googled for a solution to this and none of the answers are working.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how your system is set up.  All I can say is that your CLI is very old.

Answer (score 0):

update your firebase CLI with this command

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

then initialize your firebase with

```
firebase init
```

Now its time to deploy the project

```
firebase deploy
```